# Iterating through an associative array in a function call

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a Stripe Subscription schedule with a limit of 10 per schedule. I use `chunk` to split my array into different parts. There is function called `createSchedule`which creates the schedule. However, when it finishes although it creates two subscriptions it doesn't include all of my array items, only the first one.

Note I have truncated my array for simplicity. In the actual code there are more >20 items in the array.

```
function createSchedule ($customer, $phases) {
  $schedule = \Stripe\SubscriptionSchedule::create([
      'customer' => $customer,
      'expand' => ['subscription'],
      'start_date' => 'now',
      'end_behavior' => 'cancel',
      'phases' => $phases,
    ]);
  }

$dataset = array(
  array(
    "product" => $product->id,
    "unit_amount" => "2020",
    "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-12")) // Payment 1 Date

  ),
  array(
      "product" => $product->id,
      "unit_amount" => "2000",
      "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-15")) //Payment 2 Date
  ),
  array(
      "product" => $product->id,
      "unit_amount" => "3400",
      "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-16")) //Payment 3 Date
  ),
  array(
      "product" => $product->id,
      "unit_amount" => "3700",
      "end_date" =>  date_timestamp_get(date_create("2020-07-18")) //Payment 4 Date
  ),
);

$schedule_batch = array_chunk($dataset, 9);
$numberofbatches = count($schedule_batch);

$phases = [];
foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {
    $phases[] = [
      'end_date' => $data[$index]["end_date"],
      'transfer_data' => [
        'amount_percent' => $fee_percentage,
        'destination' => $account],        
      'proration_behavior' => 'none',
      'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => $data[$index]["unit_amount"],
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => $data[$index]["product"],
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'month',
              ],
            ],
            
          ],
        ],
    ];
  }


foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {
  createSchedule($customer->id, $phases);
}
```

Comment: from the looks of it, you need to `foreach()`  one level deeper, as `array_chunk()` returns an array of arrays.  I'm guessing `$numberofbatches === 1`

Comment: Is that for when I am calling the function or for phases aswell?

Comment: give it a try...

Comment: So I went 1 level down for the function call and now what it does is create all of the items as separate schedules when it should be in one schedule or per chunk array

Comment: it might help if you show us your expected outcome, thx

Comment: Any array up to a limit of 10 transactions need to be placed in a single schedule. Anything more than that goes into another one. It turns out as you pointed out that the phases part needed another level on the foreach. The initialisation of the phases array should also be at in between the two foreach. I will draft up a code edit now

Answer (score 0):

The foreach statement needed another level to access the array elements. Additionally, the array initialisation of `$phases = []` needed to come in between the two foreach statements.

```
foreach ($schedule_batch as $index => $data) {
  $phases = [];
  foreach ($data as $index2 => $data2)
    $phases[] = [
      'end_date' => $data2["end_date"],
      'transfer_data' => [
        'amount_percent' => $fee_percentage,
        'destination' => $account],        
      'proration_behavior' => 'none',
      'plans' => [
          [
            'price_data' => [
              'unit_amount' => $data2["unit_amount"],
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'product' => $data2["product"],
              'recurring' => [
                  'interval' => 'month',
              ],
            ],
            
          ],
        ],
    ];
  }
```